# What HTML tags can be used to send a message on Telegram Bot?

Tags: c#, html, markdown, telegram-bot

I´m developing a telegram bot in c#. 
Using the class `TelegramBotClient` in `Telegram.Bot` library.

I want to send a message with `SendTextMessageAsync` using HTML option.
In the official documentation (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) I can see this:

```
string texto = @"<b>bold</b>, <strong> bold </strong>" +
               @"<i> italic </i>, <em> italic </em>" +
               @"<a href = 'http://www.example.com/'> inline URL </a>" +
               @"<a href = 'tg://user?id=123456789'> inline mention of a user</a>" +
               @"<code> inline fixed-width code </code>" +
               @"<pre> pre - formatted fixed-width code block</pre>";

 Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: id_chat,
                          text: texto,
                          parseMode: ParseMode.HTML);
```

It works corretly but I want to use "New Lines" and "List". I have seen them on telegram official notificacion like in this photo:

[image]

I have tried `<br>, </br>, <br/>`... etc.

But I have get the

> Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: 'Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unexpected end tag at byte offset 36

Does anyone know if it´s possible to do it?

Also if possible to link a telephone number?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot

Comment: I do this replace in PHP before sending the HTML message: `str_replace('<br>', chr(10), $msg)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the next paragraph below the html-examples in the documentation, you can see that it says that `only the tags mentioned mentioned above are currently supported.`

Therefore, I would suggest you use markdown, since there are no restrictions mentioned for this way of parsing. A linebreak in MD is achieved by either `two spaces` or `<br/>`. A list in MD can be created by using `*, + or -` in front of the list's items, for more information refer to [this documentation on MD](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lists) for example.

For the second part of your question, phone numbers get highlighted by the Telegram phone app automatically, but there is no such function for Desktop-clients and no built-in way in the API/libraries. Also, it only works for messages within the range of 0-200 characters, as stated here:
[How to make phone number a link in Telegram Bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590683/how-to-make-phone-number-a-link-in-telegram-bot)

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer. I have tried MarkDown opcion as you said. 

I overviewed MD documentation for create list using ```*, + or -``` but it doesn`t work. I can conclude that Telegram doesn´t allow as so many options as MD standar support. 

For list implementation a workarround could be to use ```·``` character (the one over the number 3 in qwerty keyboard).

Thank you very muck for your time. Also for telephone detection. Now I understand it perfectly!

Comment: No problem at all! If the normal list operators for MD don't work, it's probably the Telegram documentation which is a bit fuzzy there...

Answer (score 4):

I am working with `PHP` and using `parse_mode=HTML`

I had the same problem but solved with.

```
"\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following HTML can be used for new lines:

`&#10;`